# Selenium - Can't Get Newly Generated Text In Colaboratory

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory

I made a really cool tool for Google Colaboratory. It's supposed to run a notebook, wait for n amount of time, run it again. To know when the notebook has finished, I print a string at the end of the notebook like this:

`print("forkin"+"me")`

I try to detect it like this after scrolling down the page:

```
def exists_by_text(driver, text):
    driver.implicitly_wait(0)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+str(text)+"')]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        return False
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    return True
```

but it's just not detecting the text. I use this function all the time elsewhere but it's not working in the colab notebook. Here is the entire script: [colabctl](https://github.com/TensorTom/colabctl/blob/master/colabctl.py)

**note**: If you come across this question and get the idea to use my colabctl, please read the readme of the repo first. An important message exists [there](https://github.com/TensorTom/colabctl).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `implicitly_wait()` for multiple time in your code. As per [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits), You only need to set it once.

It is always better to use explicit waits which wait only until the expected condition is met.

The problem here is, you are not using even the implicit wait before finding the element. You are setting it to zero before you try to find the element.

Try the following code:

```
def exists_by_text(driver, text):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), '"+str(text)+"')]")))
#    except NoSuchElementException:
    except TimeoutException:
        return False
    return True
```

For this you need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: That code produces a different exception so I changed it to `except Exception`. It ran but it still didn't match the text when it was printed.

Comment: Can you provide the link or HTML?

Comment: Just create an empty Google Colaboratory notebook (https://colab.research.google.com) and add to it: print("forkin"+"me")

Comment: @SAhmed As OP pointed out do you still feel `WebDriverWait` will return `NoSuchElementException` on failure?

Comment: Now it returns `TimeoutException` with the new function

Comment: I had to use `switch_to_frame` because it was in an iframe

Comment: @DebanjanB @xendi Sorry, my bad. `WebdriverWait` would return `TimeoutException`